# Issue with ls -l and grep command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, grep, ls

I have piece of code and want it to search for a string in a particular path. The script will take input strings from an input file using a while loop. Basically, I want to read that file line by line and try to find out whether the content of that line exists in the particular path or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='/input.txt'
path=/

while read -r line
do
    res=`ls -l $path | grep $line`
    echo "$res"
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode Please paste in your code using the appropriate code markdown. You should also go to the Help Center to see how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Why is most of the code commented out?

Comment: As the question stands, it is unclear exactly what problems you are facing. I suggest following chepner's advice and changing your file access strategy, if you are still facing issues, then edit your question with the relevant errors/code and a more specific explanation of what is blocking you

Comment: @WillBarnwell  Hi, actually I have tried all the ways like using if command and after that I actually want to know what is the actual output so I have commwnted for some.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, actually I have tried all the ways like using if command and after that I actually want to know what is the actual output so I have commwnted for some.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ls`, use `find`:

```
find $file -maxdepth 1
```

If you need to `grep` for the full paths, ensure that you are passing the absolute/canonical path to `find`:

```
find `readlink -f $file` -maxdepth 1
```